# Dagger/Hilt 2.32-alpha Hilt Jetpack 1.0.0-alpha03 + Dynamic Feature + ViewModel + SavedStateHandle and dagger.assisted.AssistedInject

Tags: android, dagger-hilt, dynamic-feature-module

I created a sample project to use Dagger/Hilt with dynamic feature and ViewModel and everything was working great with `Dagger/Hilt 2.29.1-alpha` and `Hilt Jetpack 1.0.0-alpha02` you can check the source code [here](https://github.com/IbrahimDisouki/CurrencyConverter/tree/develop). Now a new version of Dagger/Hilt is here which is `Dagger/Hilt 2.32-alpha Hilt Jetpack 1.0.0-alpha03` and you can check the source code [here](https://github.com/IbrahimDisouki/CurrencyConverter/tree/update_hilt). In the `app` module I created the following class to be a generic view model factory

```
package com.ibrahim.currencyconverter.di

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory
import androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory
import androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle
import androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.savedstate.SavedStateRegistryOwner
import javax.inject.Provider

class DFMSavedStateViewModelFactory(
    owner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
    defaultArgs: Bundle?,
    private val delegateFactory: SavedStateViewModelFactory,
    private val viewModelFactories: @JvmSuppressWildcards Map<String, Provider<ViewModelAssistedFactory<out ViewModel>>>
) : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(owner, defaultArgs) {

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(
        key: String,
        modelClass: Class<T>,
        handle: SavedStateHandle
    ): T {
        val factoryProvider = viewModelFactories[modelClass.name]
            ?: return delegateFactory.create("$KEY_PREFIX:$key", modelClass)
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return factoryProvider.get().create(handle) as T
    }

    companion object {
        private const val KEY_PREFIX = "androidx.hilt.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory"
    }
}
```

`FragmentViewModelModule` class in the `app` module to provide the view model factory

```
package com.ibrahim.currencyconverter.di

import android.app.Application
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory
import androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.components.FragmentComponent
import javax.inject.Provider

@Module
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
object FragmentViewModelModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideSavedStateViewModelFactory(
        application: Application,
        fragment: Fragment,
        viewModelFactories: @JvmSuppressWildcards Map<String, Provider<ViewModelAssistedFactory<out ViewModel>>>,
    ): DFMSavedStateViewModelFactory {
        val defaultArgs = fragment.arguments
        val delegate = SavedStateViewModelFactory(application, fragment, defaultArgs)
        return DFMSavedStateViewModelFactory(fragment, defaultArgs, delegate, viewModelFactories)
    }
}
```

`AppDependencies` class in the `app` model to expose required dependencies by the dynamic feature module which is the `home` dynamic feature module

```
package com.ibrahim.currencyconverter.di

import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.EntryPoint
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import retrofit2.Retrofit

@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
interface AppDependencies {
    fun exposeApplication(): Application
    fun exposeRetrofit(retrofit: Retrofit): Retrofit
}
```

Then in the `home` dynamic feature module, I created `HomeComponent` class to inject the `HomeFragment`

```
package com.ibrahim.home

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import com.ibrahim.currencyconverter.di.AppDependencies
import dagger.BindsInstance
import dagger.Component
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
@Component(dependencies = [AppDependencies::class], modules = [HomeModule::class])
interface HomeComponent {

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    fun inject(fragment: HomeFragment)

    fun fragment(): Fragment

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun fragment(@BindsInstance fragment: Fragment): Builder
        fun appDependencies(appDependencies: AppDependencies): Builder
        fun build(): HomeComponent
    }

}
```

`HomeModule` class to provide the `home` module dependencies

```
package com.ibrahim.home

import com.ibrahim.currencyconverter.di.AppModule
import com.ibrahim.currencyconverter.di.FragmentViewModelModule
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.android.components.FragmentComponent
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import retrofit2.Retrofit

@Module(
    includes = [
        FragmentViewModelModule::class,
        AppModule::class
    ]
)
@InstallIn(FragmentComponent::class)
object HomeModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideHomeRemoteDataSource(retrofit: Retrofit): IHomeRemoteDataSource {
        return retrofit.create(IHomeRemoteDataSource::class.java)
    }

    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    @Provides
    fun provideHomeRepository(repository: HomeRepository): IHomeRepository {
        return repository
    }

}
```

`HomeViewModel` class

```
package com.ibrahim.home

import androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle
import com.ibrahim.core.CoreViewModel
import com.ibrahim.core.None
import com.ibrahim.core.exhaustive
import dagger.assisted.Assisted
import dagger.assisted.AssistedInject
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import timber.log.Timber

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class HomeViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    private val latestExchangeRateUseCase: LatestExchangeRateUseCase,
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) :
    CoreViewModel<HomeIntent, HomeResult, HomeState>(HomeState.Idle) {

    override suspend fun handleIntent(intent: HomeIntent) {
        when (intent) {
            is HomeIntent.GetLatestExchangeRate -> {
                latestExchangeRateUseCase.execute(None()).collect {
                    updateState(it)
                }
            }
        }.exhaustive
    }

    override fun reduce(result: HomeResult): HomeState {
        return when (result) {
            is HomeResult.Loading -> {
                HomeState.Loading
            }
            is HomeResult.ExchangeRateSuccess -> {
                HomeState.ExchangeRateSuccess(result.exchangeRates)
            }
            is HomeResult.ExchangeRateFailure -> {
                HomeState.ExchangeRateFailure(result.failure)
            }
        }.exhaustive
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        Timber.i("HomeViewModel: onCleared()")
        super.onCleared()
    }

}
```

And finally the `HomeFragment` class

```
package com.ibrahim.home

import android.content.Context
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DividerItemDecoration
import com.ibrahim.core.Failure
import com.ibrahim.core.exhaustive
import com.ibrahim.currencyconverter.di.AppDependencies
import com.ibrahim.currencyconverter.di.DFMSavedStateViewModelFactory
import com.ibrahim.currencyconverter.exchangerate.ExchangeRateData
import com.ibrahim.home.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding
import dagger.hilt.android.EntryPointAccessors
import kotlinx.coroutines.ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collect
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import timber.log.Timber
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException
import javax.inject.Inject

@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null

    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and
    // onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    @Inject
    lateinit var savedStateViewModelFactory: DFMSavedStateViewModelFactory

    private val viewModel by viewModels<HomeViewModel> { savedStateViewModelFactory }

    private val adapter: ExchangeRatesAdapter by lazy {
        ExchangeRatesAdapter {
            val base =
                if (viewModel.state.value is HomeState.ExchangeRateSuccess) {
                    (viewModel.state.value as HomeState.ExchangeRateSuccess).exchangeRates.base
                } else {
                    ""
                }
            findNavController().navigate(
                HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToExchangeRateFragment(
                    ExchangeRateData(
                        base = base,
                        target = it.name,
                        rate = it.rate
                    )
                )
            )
        }
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        DaggerHomeComponent.builder()
            .fragment(this)
            .appDependencies(
                EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(
                    requireContext().applicationContext,
                    AppDependencies::class.java
                )
            )
            .build()
            .inject(this)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.rvRates.addItemDecoration(
            DividerItemDecoration(
                requireContext(),
                DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL
            )
        )
        binding.rvRates.setHasFixedSize(true)
        binding.rvRates.adapter = adapter

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            viewModel.state.collect { state ->
                render(state)
            }
        }

    }

    private fun render(state: HomeState) {
        when (state) {
            is HomeState.Idle -> {
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            is HomeState.Loading -> {
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            is HomeState.ExchangeRateSuccess -> {
                onLatestExchangeRateSuccess(state.exchangeRates)
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            is HomeState.ExchangeRateFailure -> {
                onLatestExchangeRateFailure(state.failure)
                binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }.exhaustive
    }

    private fun onLatestExchangeRateSuccess(exchangeRates: ExchangeRates) {
        Timber.i("latestExchangeRate: ${exchangeRates.exchangeRates.size}")
        requireActivity().title = exchangeRates.base
        if (adapter.items.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            adapter.items.addAll(exchangeRates.exchangeRates)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    private fun onLatestExchangeRateFailure(failure: Failure) {
        Timber.i("latestExchangeRateFailure: $failure")
        var errorMessage: String = getString(R.string.something_went_wrong_please_try_again_later)
        when (failure) {
            is Failure.NetworkConnection -> {
                errorMessage =
                    if (failure.throwable is SocketTimeoutException)
                        getString(R.string.looks_like_the_server_is_taking_too_long_to_respond_please_try_again_later)
                    else
                        getString(R.string.no_internet_connection)
            }
            is Failure.ServerError -> {
                errorMessage = getString(R.string.no_internet_connection)
            }
            is Failure.FeatureFailure -> {
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(
            requireContext(),
            errorMessage,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        if (viewModel.state.value !is HomeState.ExchangeRateSuccess) {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                viewModel dispatch HomeIntent.GetLatestExchangeRate
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        Timber.i("onDestroyView")
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        Timber.i("onDetach")
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Timber.i("onDestroy")
    }

}
```

I'm unable to build the project due to the following error and I don't know what is wrong and how I can fix it. Also, I have checked the [hilt-multi-module documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-multi-module)

```
/home/ibrahim/Android/Projects/CurrencyConverter/home/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/ibrahim/home/HomeComponent.java:8: error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
public abstract interface HomeComponent {
                ^
      java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<? extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>> is injected at
          com.ibrahim.currencyconverter.di.FragmentViewModelModule.provideSavedStateViewModelFactory(…, viewModelFactories)
      com.ibrahim.currencyconverter.di.DFMSavedStateViewModelFactory is injected at
          com.ibrahim.home.HomeFragment.savedStateViewModelFactory
      com.ibrahim.home.HomeFragment is injected at
          com.ibrahim.home.HomeComponent.inject(com.ibrahim.home.HomeFragment)warning: The following options were not recognized by any processor: '[dagger.hilt.android.internal.disableAndroidSuperclassValidation, kapt.kotlin.generated]'
```

Answer (score 0):

Determine the dependency you want to have in viewmodel

```
@AssistedFactory
interface HomeViewModelFactory {
    fun create(handle: SavedStateHandle): HomeViewModel
}

class HomeViewModel @AssistedInject constructor(
    private val latestExchangeRateUseCase: LatestExchangeRateUseCase,
    @Assisted private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
) : CoreViewModel<HomeIntent, HomeResult, HomeState>(HomeState.Idle) {

    companion object {
        fun provideFactory(
            assistedFactory: HomeViewModelFactory,
            owner: SavedStateRegistryOwner,
            defaultArgs: Bundle? = null,
        ): AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory =
            object : AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory(owner, defaultArgs) {
                override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(
                    key: String,
                    modelClass: Class<T>,
                    handle: SavedStateHandle
                ): T {
                    return assistedFactory.create(handle) as T
                }

            }
    }
}
```

and provide dependencies

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var homeViewModelFactory: HomeViewModelFactory

    private val viewModel: HomeViewModel by viewModels {
        HomeViewModel.provideFactory(homeViewModelFactory, this)
    }
}
```

Comment: But I want to create a generic `ViewModelFactory` not to create one for each `ViewModel`. Could you apply your solution to the shared classes?

Comment: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2287 @IbrahimDisouki